# How can the solution of an equation be a collection of expressions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Wikipedia says that a solution is an expression or a collection of expressions(one for each unknown) such that, when substituted for the unknowns, the equation becomes an identity.
So far, as I can remember, I've only came across the case of an expression to be a solution. What are some examples where a collection of expressions is a solution to an equation?

Comment: Linear equations in more than one variable?

Comment: Quadratics have 2 solutions in general.

Comment: @Ed_4434 Yes but their is a single expression having +- operation.

Comment: @ankit It depends what you mean by "collection of expressions"; often you will see the solutions written as the set $\left\{ x_1, x_2\right\}$

Comment: When asking a question about something you've read online, it helps to provide a link to where you found it.  In this case I'm guessing you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_solving

Answer (score 1):

One example is the classic parameterization for Pythagorean triples, $a=p^2-q^2$, $b=2pq$, $c=p^2+q^2$, which solve the equation $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Answer (score -1):

If you have fewer equations than unknowns, you can have expressions for the solution. Say you are given $$x-3y=2z\\ 2x+y=z$$ Given any one variable you can solve for the others, so one way to express the solution is $$y=-3z/7\\ x=16z/7$$